# JSON Send empty array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

When trying to send an array, and I know that the array contains data because I checked with var_dump, the json_encode does not send any data.
This is my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dados_atividades)-1;$i++)
    {
        $arr[$i+1]['Descricao'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['Descricao'];
        $arr[$i+1]['DataInicioPrevista'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['DataInicioPrevista'];
        $arr[$i+1]['DataConclusaoPrevista'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['DataConclusaoPrevista'];
    }
    if(count($arr)>0) {
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }else{
        $arr = array();
        $arr[0]['Descricao'] = 'N/A';
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

As you can see in the picture, the response does not contain any php echo
[image: without var_dump]

and this is my code with var_dump:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dados_atividades)-1;$i++)
    {
        $arr[$i+1]['Descricao'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['Descricao'];
        $arr[$i+1]['DataInicioPrevista'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['DataInicioPrevista'];
        $arr[$i+1]['DataConclusaoPrevista'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['DataConclusaoPrevista'];
    }
    if(count($arr)>0) {
    var_dump($arr);
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }else{
        $arr = array();
        $arr[0]['Descricao'] = 'N/A';

        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

and as you can see in the picture, the array contains data:

[image: with var_dump]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is `json_encode` returning false? Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to determine the cause, if any.

Comment: Could it be possible that the echo and json_encode is working but it isnt outputting to the page you are seeing?

Also, try a var_dump(json_encode($arr)) and see what happens

Comment: @MartinCurrah The point is that it works with small arrays, with 10 sizes +/-

Comment: @MartinCurrah with var_dump (json_encode ($ arr)), give me bool (false)

Comment: SHow us what goes on just before you start the piece of code you have shown us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon the previous answer you need to encode the array data to UTF-8

```
function utf8_converter($array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but this code actually generates 3 Warnings

Comment: give me warning like this:
"b>Warning</b>:  htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string,"

Comment: I have updated the code. Run $arr through this function before echoing it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing out the json each time round the loop, build the array in the loop and then echo the json once it has completed.

The browser is expecting to see one reply to the AJAX call and not multiple replies.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dados_atividades)-1;$i++)
{
        $arr[$i+1]['Descricao'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['Descricao'];
        $arr[$i+1]['DataInicioPrevista'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['DataInicioPrevista'];
        $arr[$i+1]['DataConclusaoPrevista'] = $dados_atividades[$i]['DataConclusaoPrevista'];
    }
}

if(count($arr) == 0) {
    $arr = array();
    $arr[]['Descricao'] = 'N/A';
}

$json_string = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

if ( json_last_error() > 0 ) {
    file_put_contents('json_debug.txt', json_last_error_msg() );
} else {
    echo $json_string;
}
exit;
```

It sounds like you are getting a `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` error, so change this line like so

```
$json_string = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Same thing, because the array contains data

Comment: same error in the txt file:
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded